# Django.staticfiles doesn't collect admin files

Tags: django, nginx, django-admin, django-staticfiles, django-static

I noticed that `staticfiles` doesn't copy the admin's static files to `STATIC_ROOT`. I was under the impression (and I can't find references for that just now) that once you include `django.contrib.staticfiles` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, it would automatically copy admin's static files (as well as all the other ones). However, it doesn't seem to be the case.

From browsing a dozen related questions on SO it seems that the accepted way is to include the hardcoded path to your `virtualenv`'d admin path to your NGINX, [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17495961/1226722):

```
location /static/admin {
  root   /webapps/hello_django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/;
}
```

However, this seems rather dirty to me.

I should also mention that finders are working for me, i.e.

```
 $ ./manage.py findstatic admin
   Found 'admin' here:
   /<path to venv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `collectstatic` should collect `admin` content and place it under `STATIC_ROOT` (not `STATIC_URL` as you mentioned). Do you see any content under your `STATIC_ROOT` when you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: Do you have 'django.contrib.admin' entry in your INSTALLED_APPS list ? As per the document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-files django pulls all the apps static files in STATIC_ROOT directory when you run collectstatic.
Also make sure you have django/contrib/admin/static path in your django installation just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a subtle problem with my `settings.py` splitting method. For anyone coming here from Google, I was following [deploydjango.com](http://www.deploydjango.com/django_project_structure/index.html#building-a-perfect-django-settings-module)'s and  strategy on splitting `settings.py`, however `ROOT_DIR` was being defined in terms of the project, i.e. the following structure

```
$ tree -L 2
.
├── static
├── apps
└── project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── base.py
    │   ├── dev.py
    │   └── prod.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

with the following setting

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ABS_PATH('apps', 'example_app', 'static'),
)
```

would result in `ROOT_DIR` being set to `project/`. And since `ABS_PATH` function defines paths based on `ROOT_DIR`, the `apps/` folder is not visible (it should be preceded with `'..'`).

The solution is of course to move `apps/` folder inside the `project/` folder, which makes sense. I.e. the correct structure is as follows:

```
$ tree -L 2
.
├── static
└── project_name
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── apps                # <-- apps moved here
    │   └── example_app
    ├── settings
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── base.py
    │   ├── dev.py
    │   └── prod.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

I realised this problem is very tied to the way I was doing things, however since this structure can be seen by some people as "best practice" (although [some disagree](http://bruno.im/2013/may/18/django-stop-writing-settings-files/)), I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have all settings set like that in your `settings.py`.
I suppose that your static files are under `static` dir in your project root folder.

```
import os 
import sys

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
# default apps
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# etc
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
```

nginx config:

```
 location /static {
        alias /path_to_your_project/static;
        access_log   off;
        expires      max;
 }
```

Comment: I'm on 1.5 and was under the impression `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` [was deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#django-contrib-admin) in 1.4.

Comment: This example is valid for Django 1.2, from live server.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and an example of a working config, but the problem turned out to be mostly due to me being new to Django. I added my answer explaining what the problem was. Have an upvote anyway!